# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type JAXBElement

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, spring-integration, spring-rest

I am posting a JAXB object to a REST service. The generated class does not have an XMLRootElement, therefore I am creating it using the Object Factory createXMl method. When I manually add the XMLRootElement it works, but that is just a workaround as the JAXB classes are always generated without the XMLRootElement. There seems to be some problem with the XMl that is marshalled while posting the request.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    String userAndPass = "Test:Test123";
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Utility.encode(userAndPass.getBytes()));

    JAXBElement<DocumentDef> documentDef = PrintFactory.createPrintObjects();

    HttpEntity<JAXBElement<DocumentDef>> request = new HttpEntity<>(documentDef, headers);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("lang", "2");

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class, map);
```

PrintFactory.java

```
      public JAXBElement<DocumentDef> createPrintObjects() {

       DocumentDef documentDef = new DocumentDef();
       JAXBElement<DocumentDef> documentDefJAXBElement = factory.createXml(documentDef);
       return documentDefJAXBElement;
       }
```

ObjectFactory.java

```
        /**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link DocumentDef }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.com/testservice", name = "xml")
public JAXBElement<DocumentDef> createXml(DocumentDef value) {
    return new JAXBElement<DocumentDef>(_Xml_QNAME, DocumentDef.class, null, value);
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement] and content type [application/xml]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:859)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:507)
```

The below HttpMessageConverters are already registered :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@68022358, org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@7b3a8b9f, org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@645e9bc0, org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter@7f438dba, org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter@2c0def9c, org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@46ee015c, org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@2c833e50, org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@339b6365, org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter@1e9a965b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by creating a .xjb file which automatically appends the XMLRootElement annotation to the parent java class while generating as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" version="1.0">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's true that it doesn't work for you because of:

```
JAXBElement<DocumentDef> documentDef = PrintFactory.createPrintObjects();
HttpEntity<JAXBElement<DocumentDef>> request = new HttpEntity<>(documentDef, headers);
```

meanwhile `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` is for this:

```
* <p>This converter can read classes annotated with {@link XmlRootElement} and
* {@link XmlType}, and write classes annotated with {@link XmlRootElement},
* or subclasses thereof.
```

and

```
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, XmlRootElement.class) != null && canWrite(mediaType));
}
```

when your `JAXBElement` is exactly without `@XmlRootElement`.

Try to figure out the solution without `JAXBElement` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Artem .. I was able to fix this by adding an .xjb file for my xsd which added the XMLRootElement to my generated java classes .. The xml is now parsing sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to post a jaxb object **that doesn't have** a `XMLRootElement` annotation using the `RestTemplate`, a solution is to use a custom `HttpMessageConverter` :

```
// jaxb context specific to your xml elements
JAXBContext jaxbContext =
    JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName());

// custom converter (see declaration below)
JaxbElementHttpMessageConverter converter = new JaxbElementHttpMessageConverter();
converter.setJaxbContext(jaxbContext);

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.getMessageConverters().add(converter); // <--- here

// your object needs to be wrapped around a JAXBElement
YourRequestObject yourObject = ...;
JAXBElement<YourRequestObject> element =
    new ObjectFactory().createYourRequestObject(request);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

ResponseEntity<YourResponseObject> response = 
    template.postForEntity("/your/url", 
                           HttpEntity<>(element, headers), 
                           YourResponseObject.class, 
                           params);
```

Note that this converter will try to convert any object wrapped into a `JAXBElement`, so you need :

1. to make sure any element you through at it can be marshalled/unmarshalled by the jaxb context you specified ;
2. add it at the end of the message converters list so more specific message converters are tried first.

The `JaxbElementHttpMessageConverter` is defined as follow :

```
/**
* Implementation of {@link org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter HttpMessageConverter} that can read and write XML using JAXB2.
*
* <p>This converter can read and write classes not annotated with {@link XmlRootElement} as long as they are wrapped into a {@link JAXBElement} and that a specific Jaxb context is provided.
*/
public class JaxbElementHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter<Object> {

        private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        private EntityResolver entityResolver = NO_OP_ENTITY_RESOLVER;

        public void setJaxbContext(JAXBContext jaxbContext) {
                this.jaxbContext = jaxbContext;
        }

        public void setEntityResolver(EntityResolver entityResolver) {
                this.entityResolver = entityResolver;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
                return clazz.isAssignableFrom(JAXBElement.class) && canRead(mediaType);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
                return clazz.isAssignableFrom(JAXBElement.class) && canWrite(mediaType);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
                // should not be called, since we override canRead/Write
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object readFromSource(Class<?> clazz, HttpHeaders headers, Source source) {
                try {
                        source = processSource(source);
                        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                        JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, clazz);
                        return jaxbElement.getValue();
                }
                catch (UnmarshalException ex) {
                        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not unmarshal to [" + clazz + "]: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

                }
                catch (JAXBException ex) {
                        throw new HttpMessageConversionException("Could not instantiate JAXBContext: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
        }

        protected Source processSource(Source source) {
                if (source instanceof StreamSource) {
                        StreamSource streamSource = (StreamSource) source;
                        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(streamSource.getInputStream());
                        try {
                                XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
                                xmlReader.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);
                                return new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);
                        }
                        catch (SAXException ex) {
                                logger.warn("Processing of external entities could not be disabled", ex);
                                return source;
                        }
                }
                else {
                        return source;
                }
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeToResult(Object o, HttpHeaders headers, Result result) {
                try {
                        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                        setCharset(headers.getContentType(), marshaller);
                        marshaller.marshal(o, result);
                }
                catch (MarshalException ex) {
                        throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not marshal [" + o + "]: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
                catch (JAXBException ex) {
                        throw new HttpMessageConversionException("Could not instantiate JAXBContext: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
        }

        private void setCharset(MediaType contentType, Marshaller marshaller) throws PropertyException {
                if (contentType != null && contentType.getCharset() != null) {
                        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, contentType.getCharset().name());
                }
        }

        private static final EntityResolver NO_OP_ENTITY_RESOLVER = new EntityResolver() {
                @Override
                public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
                        return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
                }
        };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to `canWrite` and `canRead` methods from `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` class. The methods checks if the marshaller and unmarshaller supports a class. In my case enabling jaxb element support helped.

```java
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new   MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
marshaller.setContextPath(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName());
converter.setMarshaller(marshaller);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
```